# redux-simple-router + react-router error "route state does not exist"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm getting

> Uncaught Error: Cannot sync router: route state does not exist. Did you install the routing reducer?

Code:

**reducers/index.js**:

```jsx
const rootReducer = {
  counter,
  exampleData,
  navigation,
};

const reducer = combineReducers(Object.assign({}, rootReducer, {
  routing: routeReducer
}))

//const reducer = combineReducers(rootReducer);

export default reducer
```

and

**app.jsx**:

```jsx
var __DEBUG__ = __DEBUG__ || false;
var __DEBUG_NW__ = __DEBUG_NW__ || false;

const target  = document.getElementById('app');
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const store   = configureStore(window.__INITIAL_STATE__, __DEBUG__);

syncReduxAndRouter(history, store);

const node = (
  <Root
    history={history}
    store={store}
    debug={__DEBUG__}
    debugExternal={__DEBUG_NW__}
  />
);

ReactDOM.render(node, target);
```

The error is triggered by the call to syncReduxAndRouter, but I don't see what I've done wrong.
What do I need to do to correctly use redux-simple-router ?
(Also, help to clarify the question will be appreciated)

Comment: (thanks for editing: @knowbody )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your import statement for `routeReducer`. I was having the same issue until I noticed that I had forgotten the curly braces:

```
import { routeReducer } from 'redux-simple-router';
```

Edit:
a good explanation on how `import` works on ES6: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/08/es6-in-depth-modules/

Comment: That indeed was the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine redux with immutablejs by using redux-immutablejs, your syncReduxAndRouter must be:

```
syncReduxAndRouter(history, store, (state) => state.get('routing'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Zinho's answer is a good one, most likely `routeReducer` is not what you think it is. Try logging it to console and making sure it's the reducer exported by redux-simple-router.